# Determine when $T(S^n \times S^k)$ is a trivial tangent bundle.

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, vector-bundles, fiber-bundles, fibration

My partial answer is that , to make $T(S^n \times S^k)$ trivial, a neccessary condition is that $n$ or $k$ is odd.

My argument is as follows:
Suppose $T(S^n \times S^k)$ is trivial, that is, $S^n \times S^k$ is parallelizable. In particular, there exists a global non-vanishing vector field, say $X$. It follows from Poincare-Hopf index theorem that $$\chi (S^n \times S^k)=0$$

On the other hand, by Kunneth formula, 
$H_*(S^n \times S^k)=H_*(S^n)\otimes H_*(S^k)$; and it follows that 
$$\chi (S^n \times S^k)=1+(-1)^n+(-1)^k+(-1)^{n+k}=(1+(-1)^n)(1+(-1)^k)$$
Hence, a necessary condition should be  "$n$ or $k$ is odd".

**Question**   (1) Is the condition "$n$ or $k$ is odd" a sufficient condition too?

(2) Are there some systematical methods to solve this kind of problem---determing tangent bundle or even fibre bundles over a specific manifold?

(3)Concerning the reference books related to "bundle theory", I only know Hatcher's book *"Vector bndles and K-theory"* and Bott's book *"Differential forms in algebraic topology"*. , are there any other more comprehensive reference books else?

Please help! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

(1) [Yes](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1967-018-03/S0002-9939-1967-0219082-6/S0002-9939-1967-0219082-6.pdf). Use the fact that the $TS^n$ are stably trivial. (Explicitly, embed $S^n$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and note that the normal bundle is trivial, since it clearly admits a nowhere-vanishing section. Now note that $T(S^n\times S^m) = TS^n \oplus TS^m$ and induct on $n, m$.)

(2) There are certainly a lot of results about classifying bundles by characteristic classes, up to stable trivialization, for specific classes of manifolds (e.g., closed, oriented $3$-manifolds), etc., but I don't know of a convenient algorithm.

(3) Hatcher's and Bott's books are exceptional, but I like Husemoller's "Fiber Bundles".

Comment: Thanks for your well-organized answer. For (1), I know how to prove in the special case m=1, but I don't know how to do in general case. You mentioned using induction; so, could you give some detail or just hint about how to process induction.

Comment: The "paper" linked gives the proof in full detail (it is 1 page which about 50%  is introduction).

Comment: It's described in detail in the paper I linked to. Assume without loss of generality that $n$ is odd. The point is that $S^n$ admits a nowhere vanishing section $s$; pull it over to the $TS^m$ term in $TS^n \oplus TS^m$ to trivialize it (since $\theta^1 \oplus TS^m = \nu S^m = \theta^{m+1}$, where $\theta^k$ is the rank-$k$ trivial bundle), then pull one of copies of the trivial bundle back to $TS^n$ to trivialize that one.

Comment: Sorry, but what does it mean to be stably trivial? I have searched for a definition but could not find one... Also, you said: "Explicitly, embed $S^n$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and note that the normal bundle is trivial, since it clearly admits a nowhere-vanishing section" Is this a proof that $S^n$ is stably trivial? Thanks!

Comment: @Cedric: A bundle $\xi$ is stably trivial if the sum $\xi\oplus \theta^n$ is trivial for some trivial bundle $\theta^n$.

Comment: I see. I would like to prove simply that $TS^n$ is stably trivial. So I need to find some trivial vector bundle $TM$ such that $TM \oplus TS^n$ is another trivial vector bundle, right? How can I use your comment which I quoted in my comment to prove this fact? Thank you.

Comment: @Cedric: I'm not sure exactly what else you're looking for; that bit you commented is the proof as it stands.